# Looping through a product of two arrays

Tags: ansible

I have this vars file in Ansible:

```yaml
for_create:
  client: ["VK","SB"]
  folders: ["toula","tina"]

for_delete:
  client: ["VK","SB"]
  folders: ["invoices","scripts"]

for_rename:
  client: ["VK", "SB"]
  old_name: ["home"]
  new_name: ["town"]
```

Is it possible to do something like that in YAML? The following code in Ruby

```rb
clients = ["VK", "SB"]
folders =  ["toula","tina"]

clients.each do |client|
    folders.each do |folder|
        puts "folder #{folder} for client #{client} created"
    end
end
```

To sum up I want each client to create the folders ["toula", "tina"]

I have tried a lot but I can't manage to make it loop twice for each folder.

The output of the above code

```
folder toula for client VK created
folder tina for client VK created
folder toula for client SB created
folder tina for client SB created
```

Comment: There are as of this comment [200 questions very similar to yours](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+loop+arrays), are you saying none of them address your concern, nor [the section on jinja2 data filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate the lists [*with_nested*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#with-nested-with-cartesian). For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "folder {{ item.1 }} for client {{ item.0 }} created"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ for_create.client }}"
        - "{{ for_create.folders }}"
      vars:
        for_create:
          client: [VK, SB]
          folders: [toula, tina]
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: folder toula for client VK created
  msg: folder tina for client VK created
  msg: folder toula for client SB created
  msg: folder tina for client SB created
```

To rename folders *zip* the lists

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "folder {{ item.1 }} renamed to {{ item.2 }} for client {{ item.0 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ for_rename.client }}"
        - "{{ for_rename.old_name|zip(for_rename.new_name) }}"
      vars:
        for_rename:
          client: [VK, SB]
          old_name: [home]
          new_name: [town]
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: folder home renamed to town for client VK
  msg: folder home renamed to town for client SB
```

Q: ***"Is it possible to check if the folder exists inside the loop?"***

A: Yes. It is. Use the parameters [*creates*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-creates) or [*removes*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-removes). For example, given the tree

```
shell> tree /tmp/home/
/tmp/home/
├── SB
│   └── home
└── VK
    └── home
```

The playbook below

```yaml
shell: cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - command:
        cmd: "mv {{ main_path }}/{{ item.1 }} {{ main_path }}/{{ item.2 }}" 
        removes: "{{ main_path }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ for_rename.client }}"
        - "{{ for_rename.old_name|zip(for_rename.new_name) }}"
      vars:
        main_path: "/tmp/home/{{ item.0 }}"
        for_rename:
          client: [VK, SB]
          old_name: [home]
          new_name: [town]
```

moves the files only if exist

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=['VK', 'home', 'town'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['SB', 'home', 'town'])

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> tree /tmp/home/
/tmp/home/
├── SB
│   └── town
└── VK
    └── town

2 directories, 2 files
```

The playbook is idempotent. The commands will not execute if the files are missing

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [command] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=['VK', 'home', 'town'])
ok: [localhost] => (item=['SB', 'home', 'town'])

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

You can use the module *command* the same way also to create or remove files. The next option is using the module [*file*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#ansible-builtin-file-module-manage-files-and-file-properties). For example, the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - file:
        state: touch
        path: "{{ main_path }}/{{ item.1 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ for_create.client }}"
        - "{{ for_create.folders }}"
      vars:
        main_path: "/tmp/home/{{ item.0 }}"
        for_create:
          client: [VK, SB]
          folders: [toula, tina]
```

creates the files

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [file] **********************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item=['VK', 'toula'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['VK', 'tina'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['SB', 'toula'])
changed: [localhost] => (item=['SB', 'tina'])

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
shell> tree /tmp/home/
/tmp/home/
├── SB
│   ├── tina
│   ├── toula
│   └── town
└── VK
    ├── tina
    ├── toula
    └── town
```

This task is not idempotent because the files will receive updated file access and modification times (similar to the way touch works from the command line). Preserve [*access_time*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-access_time) and [*modification_time*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html#parameter-modification_time) to make the task idempotent

```yaml
    - file:
        state: touch
        path: "{{ main_path }}/{{ item.1 }}"
        access_time: preserve
        modification_time: preserve
      ...
```

Comment: is possible to check if the folder exist inside the loop ? 
let's say i have to rename 10 folders

i want to check if exists then rename if not move on 

or if there is a time to rescue the error you get if the folder do not exist 

trying to do it like that 

    - name: "Rename folder"
      command: "mv {{ main_path }}{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.1 }} {{ main_path }}/{{ item.0 }}/{{ item.2 }}"
      with_nested:
        - "{{ for_rename.client }}"
        - "{{ for_rename.old_name }}"
        - "{{ for_rename.new_name }}"

Comment: I added examples.